# Is there a "startswith" method in pyparsing

Tags: python, parsing, pyparsing

Hey I have written a very simple parser with pyparsing which detects some tokens in a text and then replaces them with a different string. The problem is that right now my code only works with exact matches. What I'd like to do is detect partial matches too. For example if the token is "foobar" I'd like to match a word like "foobarfoo". Is there a way to do that with pyparsing? I have looked at the examples and did some research but I came up with nothing.

Thanks

EDIT:

I have a list of tokens to match and a list of words in the text. So I want a solution which takes into account this fact. The list of tokens can be quite big.

Comment: Does the generic Python [`str.startswith()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) help?

Comment: @George Eracleous What do you call _"exact matches"_ ? Do vague matches exist ? I understand that your code matches only tokens being words , not parts of words that you would like: am I right ? I don't know how to do it with **pyparsing**, but I bet that you are confronted to a difficulty because you use a tool supposed to bring facility , instead of having the facility to use the regex tool despite it is supposed to bring difficulty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Literal('foobar')+Word(pyp.alphas)` defines a pyparsing ParseExpression which requires the text to startwith `'foobar'` followed by any alphacharacter. For example:

```
import pyparsing as pyp
ident = pyp.Combine(pyp.Literal('foobar')+pyp.Word(pyp.alphas))('foo')
for match in ident.searchString('bar foobarfoo bar foobarbafoo'):
    print(match.foo)
```

yields

```
foobarfoo
foobarbafoo
```

Comment: Nice - and good catch to wrap in a Combine, otherwise pyparsing might pick skip over whitespace between the leading startswith string and the rest of the word.  If the OP also wants to match words that consist *only* of the leading string, wrap the `pyp.Word(pyp.alphas)` in an Optional.

Comment: Perfect. The only problem is that I want to do this with a list of words which can be quite big. So there might be an issue with performance cz I'll have to do this procedure for each and every word in the list.

Comment: No, just replace `pyp.Literal('foobar')` with `pyp.oneOf(list_of_all_prefix_words)`.

Answer (score 3):

Simplest would be to use a pyparsing Regex expression in your grammar:

```
startsWithFoobar = Regex(r"foobar[a-zA-Z0-9_]+")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Indeed, I could go about it this way bt i have already used pyparsing so I'd rather stay with it.

Comment: :) This *is* a pyparsing solution.